How can I export ALL my notes from my Xiaomi Redmi 9A WITH the images in them intact?
I have a Xiaomi Redmi 9A that's been loyal to me for a few years. But afraid it will die on me after I noticed its battery started to drain by itself nowadays and it's also slow since longer.
I'm scared all my school, work, and other notes will be lost since I don't have the budget for a new Xiaomi phone yet, and even if I do get one, I don't know if it would sync over all of them to that, even if I do log into my Xiaomi account on that too.
Anyway, I have notes between them that would be better on PC, like my digital diary notes which also have photos (I would like to mix them into one Word file on PC). But I don't know any specific program to export notes from Mi-Cloud to PC as Word files (and yes, with intact images). (Speaking of 3500 notes and, like, 80-90% have HD images in them).
If anyone has any idea how to do this "NotesWithImages from Mi-Cloud to PC Word365", I'm welcoming them with spread arms!

Welcome. Just a note that device recommendation is off-topic here, so it was removed from the question.

I assume you have made your notes using a special Xiaomi pre-installed app. It would help other if you would name that app and best provide a link to the app source e.g. in Play Store. Also the used app version would be helpful. That way it would be clear for everybody what app you use.

I couldn't find a Play-Store link: https://miui-notes.en.uptodown.com/android
Version: 5.3.1 (didn't update it for a while now)

Can a Poco-M6-Pro sync notes from my 9A with all images in the notes intact?
